# MySQL left join with multiple rows on right, how to combine to one row for each on left (with the field I want from the right table concated)?

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables, products, and barcodes. A product may have multiple barcodes, which is why I've separated it off into it's own table.

This is what I've tried (using CodeIgnighter's Active Record, but I've written out the query here, meaning if there is a typo, it *might* not be in my actual query):

```
SELECT
    products.id,
    products.snipe_price,
    group_concat(barcodes.barcode) as barcodes
FROM products
LEFT JOIN barcodes on barcodes.product_id = products.id
```

But this just returns one row with all of the barcodes from every product `concat`ed, how can I get one row for each product with the products barcodes?

I'd rather not have to split it up, but if there is no solution with `join` then please let me know.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need a `group by`:

```
SELECT products.id, products.snipe_price, group_concat(barcodes.barcode) as barcodes
FROM products LEFT JOIN
     barcodes
     on barcodes.product_id = products.id
group by products.id;
```

Without the `group by`, MySQL interprets the whole query as an aggregation query to summarize all the data (because of the presence of `group_concat()`, an aggregation function).  Hence it returns only one row, summarized on all the data.

Comment: Works great! would be even better if it generated the list in json format

Comment: @eyal_katz . . . If you have a question, you should ask it as a question rather than a comment.

Comment: how about multy rows in left table and multy rows in right table?